# Too few periods for decompose()

Tags: r

the error looks like this

```
decompose(samplets)
Error in decompose(samplets) : time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

i want to know whats the problem? 
I am basically writing a code forecasting using ARIMA and i want to knoe if there is any seasonality or trend in my data.

Hoping for a quick resonse!!!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you made a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your question / problem, we would find it easier to answer.

Answer (score 38):

The error is pretty self explanatory. Your time series, however you created it, has no seasonal cycles or less than 2 seasonal cycles. (This may not indicate that the data are *not* seasonal; possibly you created `samplets` incorrectly.) For example, I can reproduce the error by having a time series with 7 quarterly observations, which is clearly not two full complete seasonal cycles:

```
R> TS <- ts(1:7, frequency = 4)
R> decompose(TS)
Error in decompose(TS) : time series has no or less than 2 periods
R> TS
  Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
1    1    2    3    4
2    5    6    7
```

Likewise, if I don't specify any sub-annual frequency (i.e. `frequency = 1` in the `ts()` call creating your time series object `samplets` [which is the default]) I get the same error:

```
R> TS <- ts(1:7)
R> decompose(TS)
Error in decompose(TS) : time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

Either way, this points to you having created your `"ts"` object incorrectly by not specifying the correct `frequency` or `deltat` arguments, or you have a time series of insufficient length (number of years) to cover two full seasonal cycles.

Please read `?ts` in more detail to check you are creating `samplets` correctly. If you need further help, post a reproducible exmaple.