# Error with large frequency from stl - Time Series analysis

Tags: r, time, stl, series

I am studying Time Series with R.
Using the `stl()` command I get the error

> Error in stl(avatar_ts, s.window = "periodic") : series is not
>   periodic or has less than two periods

Below is my code.

```
avatar_ts = ts(avatar_data$Gross, start = c(2009,12), frequency=365)
st_decompose_method = stl(avatar_ts, s.window="periodic")
```

If I change the frequency to 12 or 50, the `stl()` functions runs.
However my dataset has daily observations from 2009-12-18 till 2010-11-18; a total 318 observation.

(Basically it is daily data but detected a few missing weeks since it is daily movie profit dataset)

How can I use the `stl()` function with frequency of 365 for the time series data?

Answer (score 0):

The unhelpful answer here is that you can use `stl()` on daily data if you have at least two years of observations. 
You define the `s.window` as `"periodic"` but since you have less than one year of data which is [insufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12330763/2494183).

See the example with simulated data below.

First, with your number of observations:

```
x <-rnorm(318)
d <- ts(x, start = c(2009,12), frequency = 365)
st_decompose_method = stl(d, s.window="periodic")
```

This will give the error:

```
Error in stl(d, s.window = "periodic") : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

Now with at least two years of data, so minimum of two periods:

```
x <-rnorm(731)
d <- ts(x, start = c(2009,12), frequency = 365)
st_decompose_method = stl(d, s.window="periodic")
```

Which will work.

Note by the way that your `ts` specification is incorrect as you don't provide the start day. 
To do this you could do the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33129922/2494183):

```
days <- seq(as.Date("2009-12-18"), as.Date("2010-11-18"), by = "day")
avatar_ts = ts(avatar_data$Gross, 
               start = c(2009, as.numeric(format(days[1], "%j"))), 
               frequency=365)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so much. Since less than 2 periods(two years) of data, i decided to use another method. However appreciate so much for knowledge sharing sincerely. By the way, thank you for your help, i was able to set start date as well. Thanks !